# Add Javascript into Custom Language - ACE Editor

Tags: javascript, json, ace-editor

I am using ACE editor for a custom metalanguage using JSON as base. But I want to add Javascript when the user types something like

"custom" : function(param){ .... javascript code ..... }

The idea is to highlight the javascript code using the styling already used for JS.

I am not usng the JSON highligther, just use my own.

I saw in the documentation something "Embedding a different highlighter"  (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode)

But it doesnt works. Here is my code:

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hard to do since you need to count braces to detect when javascript mode ends. The following code seems to work well

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var JsonHighlightRules = require("./json_highlight_rules").JsonHighlightRules;
var JavaScriptHighlightRules = require("./javascript_highlight_rules")
   .JavaScriptHighlightRules;

var JsonPlusHighlightRules = function() {
    JsonHighlightRules.call(this);

    this.$rules.start.unshift({  
        regex: "function",
        next: "js-start",
        token: "keyword"
    }); 
    this.embedRules(JavaScriptHighlightRules, "js-", [{ 
        regex: "[{}]", onMatch: function(val, state, stack) {
            this.next = "";
            console.log(stack, this.next, val);
            if (val == "{") {
                stack.unshift("js-start", state);
                return "paren";
            }
            if (val == "}" && stack.length) {
                stack.shift();
                this.next = stack.shift();
                if (this.next.indexOf("quasi") != -1)
                    return "paren.string";
            } 
            if (val == "}" && !stack.length) {
                this.next = "start";
            } 
            return "paren";
        }
    }], ["no_regex"]); 

};

oop.inherits(JsonPlusHighlightRules, JsonHighlightRules);

exports.JsonPlusHighlightRules = JsonPlusHighlightRules;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why require("ace/mode/javascript_highlight_rules") returns undefined?? Is there any way include this?

Comment: do you use ace-builds or ace? with ace-builds you need to include `mode-javascript.js` and `mode-json.js`, with ace it should work if you configure require paths to have ace: "path/to/ace/lib"