# How to do embedded highlightings in Ace editor if embedding requires proper brace nesting?

Tags: ace-editor

Consider the following Razor code:

```cs
    <div>@(Model.GetSomething())</div>
```

Obviously, the Razor block can only be properly identified if all parentheses are accounted for.
If I do naive embed (based on what PHP does):

```js
    var RazorLangHighlightRules = function() {
        CSharpHighlightRules.call(this);
    };

    oop.inherits(RazorLangHighlightRules, CSharpHighlightRules);

    var RazorHighlightRules = function() {
        HtmlHighlightRules.call(this);

        var razorStartRules = [{
            token : "meta.block-marker.razor",
            regex : "@\\(",
            push  : "csharp-start"
        }];

        var endRules = [{
            token : "meta.block-marker.razor",
            regex : "\\)",
            next  : "pop"
        }];

        console.log(this.$rules);
        for (var key in this.$rules)
            this.$rules[key].unshift.apply(this.$rules[key], razorStartRules);

        this.embedRules(RazorLangHighlightRules, "csharp-", endRules, ["start"]);
        this.normalizeRules();
    };

    oop.inherits(RazorHighlightRules, HtmlHighlightRules);
```

I get the first `)` from `GetSomething()` being recognized as the closing brace for Razor block, which is incorrect.

What is the right way to do that in Ace?

Comment: Hi , do have any source on the Razor mode highlighting for Ace? I wanted to edit views in the DB with some similar syntax as in VS but cannot find any thing. Could you help me?

Comment: @ppumkin I shelved it, but here is work-in-progress: https://gist.github.com/ashmind/70eee840893a209719be. It only has `@X`, `@{…}`, `@(…)`, and no `@if`, `<text>` etc. Note that you would probably need Ace sources to build it.

Comment: Ahh thanks! That will do me a treat as only need basic markup to work for simple viewbag and model inclusions. Fantastic, You should blog that somewhere as I searched 3 days and cant find anything at all. +beer

Comment: I have been trying this for hours and something just does not work. NO errors in code and all the required are loaded and it just stays black and white. I think a few things have changed since you wrote that in the API. Can you tell me which version you used I am happy to rollback just to get this working :)

Comment: @ppumkin OK, just uploaded my work within Ace to https://github.com/ashmind/ace/tree/razor-wip-shelf — get it and build it (including `node Makefile.dryice.js full`). After build open mode_creator (from local server), select mode _Razor_, document _Razor_, theme _chrome_razor_. That should work, so you'll only have to figure why it does and what do you need for it to work in your proj. Sorry, I have to sleep so I can't help more right now)

Comment: @ppumkin Note that default CSS does not have yellow rule for razor nodes, that's why I did chrome_razor. But the rule is pretty simple and can be added outside as well.

Comment: Ok. I installed Node.Js first time ever, did that full compile, barra bing, barra boom, copied over to my MVC project, included the theme and `It works!` Thats bloody awesome man. Thank you sooo much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a state to stack for every `(` and remove for `)`

```
endRules = [{ 
    regex: "[()]",
    onMatch: function(val, state, stack) {
        this.next = "";
        console.log(stack, this.next, val);
        if (val == "(") {
            stack.unshift("csharp-start", state);
            return "paren";
        }
        // val == ")"
        stack.shift();
        this.next = stack.shift() || "start";
        return this.next == "csharp-start" ? "paren" : "meta.block-marker.razor";
    }
}]
```

see also [Add Javascript into Custom Language - ACE Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513783/add-javascript-into-custom-language-ace-editor/24516791#24516791)

Comment: Ah, so you basically match both '(' and ')' for end rule so that you can count them. That's pretty cool and something I hadn't considered. Thanks!